# Запятая нужна или нет?

Tags: запятые

«Смотря, кому нездоровится» или «смотря кому нездоровится»?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не нужна, конечно! Это неразложимое сочетание, в чём можно убедиться [здесь](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_686). Это если мы говорим о значении ***в зависимости от** (того, кому нездоровится).* Ведь не кто-то же наблюдает, а кому же нездоровится.  Хотя последнее теоретически возможно в определённом контексте, и тогда запятая *будет* ставиться.

**Без запятой:**

*— Как вы их будете лечить?

— Не знаю, смотря кому нездоровится. Тут надо возраст тоже учитывать.*

**С запятой:**

*Доктор проходил по палатам, внимательно смотря, кому нездоровится.*

Comment: Запятая перед "конечно" нужна. Логические ударения: *Не нужнА, конЕчно! Конечно не нужнА!* Правило: https://i.imgur.com/1NxEny6.png

Comment: Чего нет реакции?

Comment: Не понимаю я что-то.

Comment: Прежде всего логические ударения. Сравним: *Не нужна тОчно! Не нужна конЕчно!* В случае с "конечно" так не говорят.

Comment: Спасибо, ты прав, только объяснять надо нормально. ;)