# «Нет, конечно». Нужна запятая?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, вводные-слова, частица

Как известно, в словосочетании "конечно нет" обычно не ставится запятая, когда подразумевается решительное отрицание. Например:
*— Водку будете?

— Конечно нет!*
А как быть с обратным порядком слов — ***нет, конечно***?

Comment: Отвечал в комментариях здесь: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/468235

Comment: https://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&api=1.0&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&mydocsize=&mode=main&lang=ru&sort=i_grtagging&nodia=1&text=lexgramm&parent1=0&level1=0&lex1=нет&gramm1=&sem1=&flags1=&sem-mod1=sem&sem-mod1=semx&morph1=&parent2=0&level2=0&min2=1&max2=1&lex2=конечно&gramm2=&sem2=&flags2=bexcl&sem-mod2=sem&sem-mod2=semx&morph2=

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы ответить на ваш вопрос, нужно различать частицу ‟конечно”, которая не обособляется, и вводное ‟конечно”, которое обособляется. Разница между ними в следующем: ‟конечно”, как вводное, относится к чему-то, что известно или очевидно для слушающего речь; ‟конечно”, как частица, используется говорящим для категорического пресечения сомнения у воспринимающего речь. Взгляните на примеры:

> — Зачем тебе боксировать с ним, он же профессионал?
> — Конечно, мне не победить профессионального боксера, но я просто хочу поучаствовать. (Говорящий понимает, что слушателю известно или очевидно то, к чему относится ‟конечно”.)

> — Как думаешь, у тебя есть шансы?
> — Конечно мне не победить профессионального боксера, идиот, я просто хочу поучаствовать. ( Говорящий понимает, что слушателю не известно и не очевидно то, к чему относится ‟конечно”, а это слово используется для категорического пресечения сомнений у воспринимающего речь.)

> — Вы предлагаете при таком диагнозе заниматься спортом?
> — Конечно, профессиональным спортсменом ваш сын не станет, но тренировки пойдут ему на пользу.  (Говорящий понимает, что слушателю известно или очевидно то, к чему относится ‟конечно”.)

> — Ты думаешь, что он не станет профессиональным спортсменом?
> — Конечно он не станет профессиональным спортсменом: у него средние результаты даже на региональном уровне. ( Говорящий понимает, что слушателю не известно и не очевидно то, к чему относится ‟конечно”, а это слово используется для категорического пресечения сомнений у воспринимающего речь.)

Также я обнаружил, что вводное ‟конечно” можно заменить вводным ‟как вы знаете”, а частицу ‟конечно” нельзя заменить этим вводным. Взгляните на те же примеры:

> —Зачем тебе боксировать с ним, он же профессионал?
> — Конечно [можно заменить вводным ‟как вы знаете”], мне не победить профессионального боксера, но я просто хочу поучаствовать.

> — Как думаешь, у тебя есть шансы?
> — Конечно [нельзя заменить вводным ‟как вы знаете”] мне не победить профессионального боксера, идиот, я просто хочу поучаствовать.

> — Вы предлагаете при таком диагнозе заниматься спортом?
> — Конечно [можно заменить вводным ‟как вы знаете”], профессиональным спортсменом ваш сын не станет, но тренировки пойдут ему на пользу.

> — Ты думаешь, что он не станет профессиональным спортсменом?
> — Конечно [нельзя заменить вводным ‟как вы знаете”] он не станет профессиональным спортсменом: у него средние результаты даже на региональном уровне.

В итоге, предложения: ‟Конечно нет” и ‟Нет конечно” — при любом контексте будут содержать частицу ‟конечно”, а не вводное и писаться без обособления.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133690/discussion-on-answer-by-jim-korbett----).

Answer (score 0):

*— Водку будете?*

***— НЕт, // конЕчно!***

1. При обратном порядке слов **запятая** ставится (пауза, два ударения).  ***Конечно*** является вводным словом.
2. Частицей без обособления слово ***конечно*** будет только в **препозиции** (нет паузы, одно ударение). Ударением подчеркивается только слово ***нет***, а частица  в безударной позиции.

*— Водку будете?*

***— Конечно нЕт!***

**Примечание.** Здесь не нужны даже ни правила, ни "поклонение" перед Розенталем, достаточно одной **грамматики** (частица или вводное слово) и **интонации** (одно или два ударения).

```
А это другое мнение: 
Если в предложении ‟Нет конечно” есть 
запятая, то это грубая ошибка. Да, действительно, в 
Нац. корпусе везде запятая. Отсюда и проблемы с этим 
словом: это просто грубейшая ошибка, которая 
традиционно закрепилась.
```

**[Справочник по пунктуации](https://gramota.ru/biblioteka/spravochniki/spravochnik-po-punktuatsii/konechno)**